# Xbox 360 Startup Connectivity issue

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I've recently set up my 360 to use a static IP address to sort out the NAT problems that I keep running into. This works fine, but has introduced a new problem. When I first turn on the console, it signs into my profile automatically, but stays offline. If I try to connect (regardless of whether it's via the Guide menu, Home Screen option, or otherwise), it fails to connect. This repeats as long as I keep trying to connect.

However, if I turn the console off and then immediately turn it back on again, I sign into LIVE immediately, with no problems. Has anyone experienced this before? And does anyone know of a solution?

I'm not at home at the moment, but if needed, I can grab the error code the console gives me (though this might have to be tomorrow - I only get this issue once per day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue, check that if you're using a manual IP you're also using manual DNS settings. I wasn't and since entering them, I've not had an issue.

Comment: You might try changing your configuration so that your router always assigns your xbox the same ip address still allowing you to use the automatic configuration settings.